# Drawing lines between two points using MACD Indicator on Pinescript V5

Tags: pine-script, line, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have identified two value points on the MACD indicator that I want to connect with a line to visualize a trend. I've used the Line tool from the Drawing Tools menu, but I want to be able to "script" the code to reduce error.

Point A = MACD crossover
Point B = MACD crossunder

Could someone kindly guide me through correcting my script below?

I am getting the following error:
"The 'symbol' and 'timeframe' arguments are incompatible with functions that have side effects"

Here is the script I am attempting to use:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD-MAIN", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
// Getting inputs
MACDSettings    = input.bool(title="MyMACD Settings:", defval=true)
MACDfast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=8) 
MACDslow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=21)
source          = input(title="Source", defval=close)
SignalLength    = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 8)
sma_source      = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal      = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

//*****************************************************************************************************************************
// Calculating
//*****************************************************************************************************************************
fast_ma         = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, MACDfast_length) : ta.ema(source, MACDfast_length)
slow_ma         = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, MACDslow_length) : ta.ema(source, MACDslow_length)
MyMACDSignal    = fast_ma - slow_ma
plot(MyMACDSignal, title="MyMACD Signal", color=color.rgb(43, 130, 35, 80),style=plot.style_line, display=display.all)
MyMACDLine      = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(MyMACDSignal, SignalLength) : ta.ema(MyMACDSignal, SignalLength)
plot(MyMACDLine, title="MyMACD Line", color=color.rgb(255, 109, 72, 80),style=plot.style_line, display=display.all)
MACDcross       = ta.cross(MyMACDSignal,MyMACDLine)

//*****************************************************************************************************************************
// Momentum
//*****************************************************************************************************************************

// Plotting the Line connecting the crossovers
CrossingValue = ta.valuewhen(MACDcross, MyMACDLine, 0)

/// Variables to track cross
var float CrossingBar = na
var float MojoValue = na

// Update crossover and crossunder values and bars
if CrossingValue
    CrossingBar := bar_index
    MojoValue   := MyMACDLine

// Plot Vertical Lines at Crossover Points
line.new(x1=bar_index[CrossingValue], y1=MyMACDLine, x2=bar_index[CrossingValue], y2=MyMACDLine, color=color.blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have found 1 solution.  If there is any more insight, please let me know! Instead of creating a "trend" type line, I plotted a line by smoothing out the values

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD-MAIN", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
// Getting inputs
MACDSettings    = input.bool(title="MyMACD Settings:", defval=true)
MACDfast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=8) 
MACDslow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=21)
source          = input(title="Source", defval=close)
SignalLength    = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 8)
sma_source      = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal      = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

//*****************************************
// Calculating
//*****************************************
fast_ma         = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, MACDfast_length) : ta.ema(source, MACDfast_length)
slow_ma         = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, MACDslow_length) : ta.ema(source, MACDslow_length)
MyMACDSignal    = fast_ma - slow_ma
plot(MyMACDSignal, title="MyMACD Signal", color=color.rgb(43, 130, 35, 80),style=plot.style_line, display=display.all)
MyMACDLine      = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(MyMACDSignal, SignalLength) : ta.ema(MyMACDSignal, SignalLength)
plot(MyMACDLine, title="MyMACD Line", color=color.rgb(255, 109, 72, 80),style=plot.style_line, display=display.all)
MACDcross       = ta.cross(MyMACDSignal,MyMACDLine)

//******************************
// Momentum
//******************************            
    // Plotting the Line connecting the crossovers
CrossingValue   = ta.valuewhen(MACDcross, MyMACDLine, 0)
MomentumLength  = input.int(title="Momentum Length: ",  minval = 1, maxval = 255, defval = 13)
SmoothCrossing  = ta.sma(CrossingValue, MomentumLength)
plot(SmoothCrossing, color = color.yellow)
```